# Delete-User-Data extension logs say it worked, but the data still shows in the Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-extensions

**Delete User Data extension logs say it worked, but the data still shows in the Firebase Console**

I've been struggling with this for a while. I'm using React.

I installed the extension running: *firebase ext:install firebase/delete-user-data*

The configuration is ok imo. I only have data in the Cloud Firestore. I have nothing in Realtime or Storage. I manage my users with Authentication.

The collection where my users are is called users. My Cloud Firestore paths is "users/{UID}". I haven't defined paths for the other 2, but I also tried configuring them to the same just in case at some point. The delete mode is configured as Recursive. Auto discovery disabled, search function URL not set. Events disabled as well.

I made sure to deploy the extensions with firebase deploy --only extensions in the terminal. I also tried deploying the whole thing with "firebase deploy". I made sure to run build as well.

I have Blaze, so this is not a subscription problem either.

These are the logs of one attempt to delete from Auth:

```
2023-05-30 12:35:06.736 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Function execution started

2023-05-30 12:35:06.758 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Started extension execution with configuration

2023-05-30 12:35:06.758 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Deleting user data from Cloud Firestore

2023-05-30 12:35:06.758 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Deleting: 'users/bsHpYFlKI5T8mm3jLjtK0C4BWYW2' from Cloud Firestore with recursive delete

2023-05-30 12:35:06.762 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Realtime Database paths are not configured, skipping

2023-05-30 12:35:06.762 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Cloud Storage paths are not configured, skipping

2023-05-30 12:35:10.138 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Deleted: 'users/bsHpYFlKI5T8mm3jLjtK0C4BWYW2' from Cloud Firestore with recursive delete

2023-05-30 12:35:10.138 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Finished deleting user data from Cloud Firestore

2023-05-30 12:35:10.138 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Successfully removed data for user: bsHpYFlKI5T8mm3jLjtK0C4BWYW2

2023-05-30 12:35:10.141 CLT ext-delete-user-data-clearData ill3f3ywf54d Function execution took 3404 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

These are my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is that if I delete a user from Auth, the logs say that the other data was deleted, but I can still see it in the Firebase console. Am I misunderstanding the logs? What is happening? Btw, I've been clearing the cache as well.

Comment: Did you found the solution? same here , logs says:  ``Realtime Database paths are not configured, skipping ``. and we specified the path for the RealtimeDatabase